# iOS 7.1 minimal ui causing problems with viewport height css unit (vh)

Tags: html, css, iphone, safari, ios7.1

since iOS 7.1 when you scroll down a page the viewport size changes but that doesnt update 100vh is there any way to stop the minimal ui or update the viewport on scroll?.

example site http://goo.gl/Umbd47

I have included a picture of the problem below and one of how it should look.

[image: example of viewport height being wrong]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the scrolling element is not `body`, minimal UI should not activate.

Wrap your content in a `div` with `overflow: auto` and set your body's `overflow` to `visible`. Both `body` and the `div` must have their heights and widths set to `100%`.

So your css might look like:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: but that breaks the sticky nav bar and the navigation buttons on the page.

Comment: You'd have to change your sticky javascript to use the scroll event/properties of the div, rather than the document's. If you only have to support iOS, you could use `position: sticky`, which should work (I did a quick test wrapping the following demo's page's content with a div with the css from my answer, and it worked). [demo page](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit)